# Columns headings to date time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

[image: Data Frame]

I have a data frame with a time series with column headings as strings, I'm trying to convert to date time.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.columns[4:308]).to_pydatetime

<bound method inherit_from_data.<locals>.method of DatetimeIndex(['1996-01-31', '1996-02-29', '1996-03-31', '1996-04-30',
              '1996-05-31', '1996-06-30', '1996-07-31', '1996-08-31',
              '1996-09-30', '1996-10-31',
              ...
              '2020-07-31', '2020-08-31', '2020-09-30', '2020-10-31',
              '2020-11-30', '2020-12-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-02-28',
              '2021-03-31', '2021-04-30'],
             dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=304, freq=None)>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think the reason for the result being not super useful is because you need `()` at the end of the line of code. I don't remember exactly how these things work, but it isn't actually calling the function without the `()` and instead is giving you some info about the function, which isn't useful here.

Second, I don't think that `pd.to_datetime` changes the dataframe, it just returns a value (the argument converted to a datetime). You need to actually change the column objects.

With those things in mind, this line should be helpful:

`df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[n]:pd.to_datetime(df.columns[n]).to_pydatetime()})`

In my testing, running this and thening checking `type(df.columns[n]` is returning `datetime.datetime` whereas before it was `str`. For example, in the screenshot below I changed the first column from `'1/1/2021'` to a datetime, and didn't change the second column. Notice that it does have date and time.

[image]

You could easily combine this with a loop

```
for n in range(4:308): #check that it starts and ends where you want
    df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[n]:pd.to_datetime(df.columns[n]).to_pydatetime()})
```